# AngularJS - max validation not working on time input

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, time

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5.3.

I have an input form with a time input box.

I need to have validation on the box such that the user cannot pick a time in the future.

Here is a snippet:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as accvm">
    <form name="accvm.addForm" novalidate>
        <div class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : accvm.addForm.time.$invalid }">
            <span class="input-label">'Time'</span>
            <input name="time" type="time" id="timeInput" max="{{ accvm.data.maxTime | date:'HH:mm' }}" ng-model="accvm.data.time" ng-change="accvm.timeChange()" style="text-align: right" required />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

For some reason, my validation always fires off and says the value is wrong. I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/aubz88/j25jwtL2/

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding date inputs are not very good with limiting the input. You can add a min value and then when ever the user adds to the time instead of adding, it will reset to the min value.
I would recommend using something like bootstrap's datepicker that does offer you what you are looking for but in a form of an actual datepicker.

For the documentation https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker
Which you can use the maxDate property to set max date...

Also from the definition in w3schools max and min don't work in certain browsers "The max attribute will not work for dates and time in Internet Explorer 10+ or Firefox, since IE 10+ and Firefox does not support these input types."

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using 1970 instead of the current year, the max value worked.

```
        var time = new Date(
            1970, //today.getFullYear(),
            0, //today.getMonth(),
            1, //today.getDate(),
            today.getHours(),
            today.getMinutes(),
            0,
            0
        );
```